# two jobs at same line of cron

Tags: unix, cron

How are the  executed, if two jobs schedules in same cron line: **parallely or sequentially?**

e.g:

```
0 3 * * * ./fillers.sh > /dev/null 2>&1; ./pionner.sh > /dev/null 2>&1;
```

Comment: When you want to control both jobs independently just make 2 crontab entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, that's one job, not two. The command is passed to `/bin/sh` to be executed. The two sub-commands are executed sequentially, jus as if you had typed the same command at a shell prompt.

If you want them executed in parallel, use an `&` after the first sub-command rather than a `;`.